# Show similar article with same field

Tags: views, 8

My articles have a field called co-author who is a relationship to other content type. Then I need to make a view (block), that when seeing an article this block show a list of other articles that have the same field (co-author). I think that is done by the contextual filters but so far I could not.

**EDIT:**

I have:

```
Content type: Article
Fields:
 - Title
 - Body
 - co-author (reference entity to co-author content type).
 - .....

Content type: Co-Author
Fields:
 - Name
 - Image
 - .....
```

All content:

```
NID   Title              co-author   ....
 1     Dummy content A    Foo (3)    ....
 2     Dummy content B    Bar (4)    ....
 5     Dummy content C    Foo (3)    ....
 6     Dummy content D    Foo (3)    ....
```

Then I need when I visit "Dummy content A" the block show me the following list:

```
- Dummy content C
- Dummy content D
```

Comment: Please write an explicit question. So far you've vaguely stated your need for a contextual filter. That's not very helpful for anyone trying to answer a question; they can only guess at what your question/problem is.

Comment: A block that shows nodes of the same co-author based on reference field when viewing a node. Seems fairly clear to me, the only unclear part is what that reference is exactly, really a content type?

Comment: In short, if it is a content type, you need multiple relationships, through the field to the referenced content type, and then on that a reverse relationship back to your node type and then a contextual filter on that reverse relationship on the node id with the current node as argument. And second, to exclude the current node, a second contextual filter that is not the node with the current id.